# Flask app in Python constantly showing an error which I cannot understand

Tags: python, linux, flask, conda

```
import config
from server import app

Config = config.Config()
ipServer = Config.ipServer
portServer = Config.portServer
debug = Config.debug
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=debug, host=ipServer, port=portServer)
```

This is main.py file whenever I run `python main.py` I get this error which I cannot understand at all, please help me find my mistake.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abledtaha/Projects/upm/upm_server/src/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from server import app
  File "/home/abledtaha/Projects/upm/upm_server/src/server.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/home/abledtaha/anaconda3/envs/upm_server/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .app import Flask as Flask
  File "/home/abledtaha/anaconda3/envs/upm_server/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import cli
  File "/home/abledtaha/anaconda3/envs/upm_server/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .helpers import get_debug_flag
  File "/home/abledtaha/anaconda3/envs/upm_server/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 14, in <module>
    from werkzeug.urls import url_quote
ImportError: cannot import name 'url_quote' from 'werkzeug.urls' (/home/abledtaha/anaconda3/envs/upm_server/lib/python3.12/site-packages/werkzeug/urls.py). Did you mean: 'unquote'?
```

It is an old project of mine which I last ran on my Windows about a year ago maybe but have no idea what is going on now even though I did not make any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be related to a version mismatch or change in the Flask and Werkzeug libraries. The `url_quote` function appears to have been removed in newer versions of Werkzeug.

You can try to upgrade Flask:

```
pip install --upgrade flask
```

or downgrade Werkzeug:

```
pip install werkzeug==0.16.0
```

to see if that resolves the error.

Comment: Downgrading my werkzeug worked but as my Flask is of version 2.1.3 and requires the minimum version 2.0 of werkzeug I just downgraded to 2.0 rather than 0.16.0

Comment: Great!  Glad this was helpful.